# How to prevent Feature component executes before custom action in WIX

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I need to install a wix msi package with registry values. After executing the setup i have to do some registry entries. I have done component ref inside feature element.  But always registry runs before creates after the execution.

How do i prevent feature component before custom action ??

Comment: It sounds like you're focusing on changing the order, but what about the order causes a problem? In Windows Installer, it may be easier to address that problem than to change the order.

Comment: @MichaelUrman actually one third party application exe runs with my wix installation setup and creates some registry values during installation. But i need to modify some registry values after that. but it is not working. I think that Registry might be created in feature and after that setup runs.

Comment: I think you need a more precise question and description of the problem.. It wasn't clear that were doing another install until you replied to a comment. Are your registry entries written by custom action code? By WiX registry items? Where does your other setup run exactly? In addition you mention of features and custom actions implies that you believe the order of installation is one feature, then another, then another, but this is not how installs work.